# GLSL : Why are my calculated normals not working properly

Tags: glsl, fragment-shader, raytracing

I am trying to follow the [Ray Tracing in one Weekend tutorial](https://raytracing.github.io/books/RayTracingInOneWeekend.html) and my normals do not look like i expect them to look.

```
float hit_sphere(Sphere sphere, Ray r){
    vec3 oc = r.origin - sphere.center;
    float a = dot(r.direction,r.direction);
    float b = 2.0 * dot(oc, r.direction);
    float c = dot(oc, oc) - sphere.radius * sphere.radius;
    float discriminant = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    if(discriminant > 0){
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        return (-b -sqrt(discriminant))/(2.0 * a);
    }
}

vec3 at(Ray ray, float p){
    return ray.origin + p * ray.direction;
}

void main()
{
    vec3 camera_origin = vec3(0,0,2);
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/vec2(x, y);
    Ray r = Ray(camera_origin, normalize(vec3(st.x - 0.5, st.y - 0.5, 1.0)));

    Sphere sphere = {vec3(0,0,0),0.5};
    float p = hit_sphere(sphere, r);
    
if(p < 0.0){
    vec3 N = normalize(at(r, p) - sphere.center);
    FragColor = vec4(N.x + 1, N.y + 1, N.z + 1, 1);
}
else{
    // FragColor = vec4(st.xy, 1.0, 1.0);
    FragColor = vec4(1 - st.y+0.7, 1 - st.y+0.7,1 - st.y+0.9, 1.0);
}
}
```

Note that the `+ 1` in each normal color channel is to make it more noticeable to spot the color difference.
This is how my normals look.
[image]

Although this is not how i expect these normals to be.
They should be something like this (not exactly like this but close)

[image]

What mistake or overseen problem is causing this.

Note : Moving back and forth doesnt change the situation[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression

> ```c
> FragColor = vec4(N.x + 1, N.y + 1, N.z + 1, 1);
> ```

creates colors in range [0, 2]. However, the color channels have to be in range [0, 1]:

```c
FragColor = vec4(N.xyz * 0.5 + 0.5, 1);
```

Note that you can also use `abs` to represent the normals:

```c
FragColor = vec4(abs(N.xyz), 1);
```

or even scale with the reciprocal maximum color channel:

```c
vec3 nv_color = abs(N.xyz); 
nv_color     /= max(nv_color.x, max(nv_color.y, nv_color.z));
FragColor     = vec4(nv_color, 1.0);
```

---

You draw the normal vector when `discriminant > 0` with p is -1. Actually you always calculate `normalize(at(r, -1) - sphere.center)`. This is wrong, because p needs to be the distance from origin to the pint on the sphere where the ray hits the sphere.

When the ray hits the sphere, `p` is >= 0. In this case you want to draw the normal vector:

<s>`if (p < 0.0)`</s>

```c
if (p >= 0.0) {
    vec3 N = normalize(at(r, p) - sphere.center);
    FragColor = vec4(N.xyz * 0.5 + 0.5, 1);
}
```

<s>`discriminant > 0`</s>

```c
if (discriminant < 0){
    return -1;
}
else {
    return (-b -sqrt(discriminant))/(2.0 * a);
}
```

Comment: Why `if(p < 0.0)` ?

Comment: @ExtorcProductions Your code is messed up. You draw the normal vector when `discriminant > 0` and `p` is -1. Actually you always calculate `normalize(at(r, -1) - sphere.center)`. This is definitely wrong, because `p` needs to be the distance from `orgin` to the pint on the sphere where the ray hits the sphere.

Comment: Okay , i will try to correct that.

Comment: I made some corrections to my code , https://imgur.com/a/Lmu1fLG if this image is correct , then you can write the answer as what you said in the last comment.

Comment: @ExtorcProductions I've already changed the answer. This is the correct image. You have no blue component, because the z axis is inverted. Try  `FragColor = vec4(-N.xyz * 0.5 + 0.5, 1);`